# When does a function has a local Minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Lets consider a function $f$ differentiable (1-times) on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_0^+$. If the restriction $f_{|\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}}$ has in $(0,0)$ a local minimum, what must the function satisfy to have $(0,0)$ as a local minimum without restriction? Means that $f$ has a local minimum in $(0,0)$.

The answer ist $\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(0,0)>0$.

Does anyone see why?

Comment: Think about about $f(x,y) = x^2 - y$ as what can go wrong without the condition on the $y$-partial derivative.

Comment: Sorry, don't see it. Has this function a local minimum at all in $(0,0)$?

Comment: So fixing any $y$ value, the above function is just a cup-up parabola which attains its minimum at $x=0$.  But, the issue is that when we un-fix $y$, as $y$ increases, the value $f(0,y)$ is *decreasing*.  So in that sense, $f(0,0)$ can't be a local minima: increasing $y$ by an arbitrarily small amount decreases $f$, i.e. $f(0,0) > f(0, \varepsilon)$.  So to prevent things like this, we need the partial derivative in $y$ to be *positive* so that if we were to increase $y$ a bit, $f(0,\varepsilon)$ wouldn't be smaller than $f(0,0)$.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I have an Idea what is meant by problem. But how could I prove that $f$ has a local minimum in $(0,0)$ using this now?

Comment: Well, if the $y$-partial is positive at $(0,0)$ and so too is the $x$-partial, then is there any direction you can go from $(0,0)$ which *decreases* the value of $f$?